# Unrecognised javascript syntax

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have come across a particular javascript code while looking into [RxJs documentation](https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators).

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

map(x => x * x)(of(1, 2, 3)).subscribe((v) => console.log(`value: ${v}`));
```

I understand what it does but I have not come across this syntax before as far as I remember. Which syntax is this?

**EDIT:**

I was confused about the part `map(x => x * x)(of(1, 2, 3))`. @Olian04 nicely explains that `map()` is an higher order function. `map()` returns an function which is passed the parameter `of(1, 2, 3)`

Comment: Thanks, I will move the question to the correct forum

Comment: I have asked the moderator to move this to stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't specify exactly which part of the snipped was confusing you, I'll do a quick breakdown of the code excluding the imports:

- `x => x*x` is an arrow function. Its the same as `function(x){return x*x;}`
- `map` is a higher order function that takes a function as its argument `map(f)`. It also returns a function `fMap = map(f)`
- `fMap` is a function that takes an observable as an argument, and 
  returns an observable where each value has had the function `f` applied on it `fObs = fMap(obs)`
- `of` is a function that takes any number of arguments, and returns an observable that will emit those arguments as events to subscribers `obs = of(1, 2, 3)`
- `fObs.subscribe` is a higher order function that takes a function as its argument and registers it as an event subscriber
- `` `value: ${v}` `` is a string literal template which is the same as doing `'value: ' + String(v)`

Comment: nicely explained!  might also be worth pointing out that `(v) => ...` is the same as `v => ...`, they are both arrow functions that take one parameter

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was particularly confused about how `map(x => x * x)` was immediately before `(of(1, 2, 3))`. Now I know something which is called [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

Comment: @ArnabDas that's great. Feel free to accept the answer, that way other users will see that the question has been answered.

Comment: @ArnabDas `map` is not an IIFE. It's a higher order function, that takes a function and returns a function. An IIFE is a function that is invoked at the same time as its defined. These concepts might look alike, but they are not the same.